# Creating fractional area coverages spatially for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

Some background first, I am working on a model that works with elevation bands. Elevation bands in sense that user defines the number of elevation bands in the area (just like reclassification of DEM under equal intervals). So, in case of my DEM, the minimum and maximum elevation is 1722.35 meters and 4196.3 meters, and if I want the 5 elevation bands, I would do (maximum elevation - minimum elevation)/5 = 495 meters (interval).Moreover, the fishnet/grid raster are approximately 6 km in resolution. So a particular grid cell can have 0-5 elevation bands in it. The Python script that I am using takes four inputs (the data can be accessed from [here](https://app.box.com/s/8qg5e8qif9r8hqr7han440zdw61mlxfn) (the course resolution grid raster, DEM, .txt file) to write data to and the interval as follows:

```
python format_snow_params.py ~/VIC_GRID_Rstr1.tif ~/DEM.tif ~/snow_params.txt 495
```

This script performs two passes. The first one loops through the grid cells to find the maximum number of elevation intervals (ie. the maxbands variable). The second pass then gets the actual elevation band values and fractional coverage for those bands. The number of bands are needed for writing the parameter file because VIC expects each cell to have the same number of band information written even though there may not be that many bands in a grid cell.

maxbands is calculated at the end of the first pass then the script moves to the second pass.

The model requires that the sum of fractional area coverages of the elevation bands in a grid cell is equal to one. a snippet of the output file is as follows:

```
287909  0.5783  0.3905  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  2404.7144   2561.4426   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.5783  0.3905  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
286980  0.7016  0.2673  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  2407.4819   2518.9944   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.7016  0.2673  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

[image]
The script (works in py 3) is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import warnings
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

# set system to ignore simple warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

def format_snow_params(basinMask,elvHiRes,outSnow,interval):
    """
    FUNCTION: format_snow_params
    ARGUMENTS: basinMask - path to template raster to run VIC model at
               elvHiRes - path elevation raster dataset at native resolution
               outsnow - path output snow parameter file
               interval - vertical distance to do equal interval segmentation
    KEYWORDS: n/a
    RETURNS: n/a
    NOTES: Does not return a variable but writes an output file
    """

    band = 1 # constant variable for reading in data

    interval = int(interval) # force equal interval value to be int type

    # make a list of input raster files
    infiles = [basinMask,elvHiRes]

    # try to read in the raster data
    try:

        # read basin grid raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[0],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        mask = BandReadAsArray(b1)
        maskRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
        ds = None
        b1 = None

        # read hi res elevation raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[1],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        elvhires = BandReadAsArray(b1)
        clsRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
        ds = None
        b1 = None

    # if not working, give error message
    except AttributeError:
        raise IOError('Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct')

    # mask elevation values less than 0
    #elvHiRes=elvhires.astype(np.float)
    elvhires[np.where(elvhires<0)] = np.nan

    # get ratio of high resoltion to low resolution
    clsRatio = int(maskRes/clsRes)

    # check if the output parameter file exists, if so delete it
    if os.path.exists(outSnow)==True:
        os.remove(outSnow)

    nbands = [] # blank list

    # try to write to output snow parameter file
    try:

        with open(outSnow, 'w') as f:

            cnt = 1 # set grid cell id counter

            # pass counter
            pass_counter = range(2)

            # perform two passes on the raster data
            # 1) to grab the maximum number of bands for a given pixel
            # 2) to calculate the snow band parameters and write to output file
            for pass_cnt in pass_counter:

                # loop over each pixel in the template raster
                for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
                    cy1 = i*clsRatio
                    cy2 = cy1+clsRatio

                    for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
                        cx1 = j*clsRatio
                        cx2 = cx1+clsRatio

                        # get all hi res pixels in a template pixel
                        tmp = elvhires[cy1:cy2,cx1:cx2]
                        if tmp.size == 0:
                            tmp=tmp2[:]
                    
                        
                        # create blank array for number of bands calculation...
                        if mask[i,j] > 1:
                             # ...if it is not a masked pixel
                            tmp2=tmp

                            if np.all(tmp == np.nan) == True:
                                tmp[:,:] = 0
                
                            # find min and max values for interval
                            minelv = np.nanmin(tmp.astype(int)) - (np.nanmin(tmp.astype(int))%interval)
                            maxelv = np.nanmax(tmp.astype(int)) + (np.nanmax(tmp.astype(int))%interval)
                        
                            #print(np.min(tmp).mask)
                            # create an array of band limits
                            bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval,interval)

                            bcls = np.zeros_like(tmp)
                            bcls[:,:] = -1

                            # get the number of bands per pixel
                            for b in range(bands.size-1):
                                bcls[np.where((tmp>=bands[b])&(tmp<bands[b+1]))] = b # band counter

                                # if it's the first pass get number of bands for each pixel
                                if pass_cnt == 0:
                                    uniqcnt = np.unique(bcls[np.where(tmp>0)])
                                    nbands.append(uniqcnt.size) # save to a list for second pass

                            if pass_cnt == 1:
                                uniqcnt = np.unique(bcls[np.where(tmp>0)])
                                #clscnt = np.bincount(tmp.ravel())

                                f.write('{0}\t'.format(mask[i,j])) # write grid cell id

                                # find frational area for each band and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        num = np.float(bcls[np.where(bcls>=0)].size)
                                        if num == 0:
                                            num = np.float(idx[0].size)
                                        frac = np.float(idx[0].size) / num
                                    except IndexError:
                                        frac = 0
                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(frac))

                                #calculate the mean elevation for each band and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        muelv = np.nanmean(tmp[idx])

                                    except IndexError:
                                        muelv = 0

                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(muelv))

                                # calculate the precipitation fractions and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        num = np.float(bcls[np.where(bcls>=0)].size)
                                        if num == 0:
                                            num = np.float(idx[0].size)
                                        frac = np.float(idx[0].size) / num
                                    except IndexError:
                                        frac = 0
                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(frac))
                                f.write('\n') # write return value for new line

                        if pass_cnt == 1 & mask[i,j] == 1:
                            cnt += 1 # plus one to the grid cell id counter

                if pass_cnt == 0:
                    maxbands = max(nbands) # maximum number of bands for a pixel

        # print the number of bands for user to input into global parameter file
        print('Number of maximum bands: {0}'.format(maxbands))

    # except raise an error when it doesn't work
    except IOError:
        raise IOError('Cannot write output file, error with output snow parameter file path')

    return

def main():
    n_args = len(sys.argv)

    # Check user inputs
    if n_args != 5:
        print ("Wrong user input")
        print ("Script writes the snow band parameter file for the VIC model")
        print ("usage: python format_snow_params.py <template raster> <elevation raster> <output snow band file> <interval for snow bands>")
        print ("Exiting system...")
        sys.exit()

    else:
        # Pass command line arguments into function
        format_snow_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])

    return

# Execute the main level program if run as standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now the script works fine, but the script does not tell how are the elevation bands are spatially distributed in a grid cell (pixel/fishnet polygon of the grid) as the model is not concerned with spatial information. But part of my analysis is create the same elevation bands in ArcMap, such that it tells me the how the elevation bands are spatially distributed in the grid this would enable me to slice the grid cell polygon according to the fractional areas of the elevation bands in each grid cell.

So far I have used the Contour tool in ArcMap with the same interval as used in the script, and set the processing extent to particular grid polygon, but the distribution does not match although the tool creates the same number of elevation bands (5) just like the script. So I am not using the right way in ArcMap.

How can I perform this task in ArcMap?

Comment: I included the full code in case someone wants to try the code with the sample data provided, so the answers can be matched with the results of the code. If you still want I can reduce or even remove the code. Please advise

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst? A reclassify https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000 with a remap range https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m0000007m000000 followed by raster to polygon https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000 (IN_MEMORY workspace would help here) then intersect https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/ the grid polygons with band polygons and summarize https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000

Comment: You would need to use a statistics field of shape area, statistics type sum and case fields of band identifier and grid identifier which would leave you with a table that will list every unique grid identifier and band identifier combination and the sum of the area for that combination. Does that sound like what you're after?

Comment: @ Micheal Stimson, yes I do have spatial analyst. I will start working on these steps. My only question is that my data is in WGS 84 so for the statistics field step (and I am thinking of using the tabulate area tool), would I need to change the coordinates to UTM?

Comment: I am assuming that your term WGS84 means WGS84/geographic CRS. Yes, if you want the results to have meaningful areas, no if you only want percent of each band type cover of each grid square. Hint: when you're intersecting the grid with the polygons set arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-coordinate-system.htm to your projected coordinate system, this eliminates the need for an extra projection step, retaining your data in WGS84/Geographic as long as possible; projecting your raster should be avoided.